# React render parent after child ready

Tags: reactjs

My child component needs to fetch data from the server.
The child component will delay showing because I update the child state after I got the data.

What I want is the full form parent + child show at the same time.

Do there any good way to let the parent render after the child is ready? or let them show together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `redux` you can use a state variable to notify if the data is being fetched or has completed being fetched and in turn use that variable to know if the parent should render or not

```
 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const {dataFetched} = state;
    return {dataFetched};
 }

 ..............

 render() {
    const {dataFetched} = this.props;
    if (dataFetched) {
      return <Parent> <Child /> </Parent>
    }
    return <div> Loading ... </div>
 }
```

if you are not using `redux` you can pass your `dataFetched` state to the parent via a prop.

```
 dataFetched = () => {
   this.setState({'dataFetched': true})
 }


 render() {
   if (this.state.dataFetched) {
     return (<Parent>
               <Child 
                 dataFetched={this.dataFetched}
               />
             </Parent>)
   }
   return <Child 
       dataFetched={this.dataFetched}
     />
 }
```

In both the cases you need to let your parent know that the child has actually finished fetching the data. How you do it is completely your choice :)